# Maximizing profit, using GAMS?

Tags: optimization, constraint

I've been given the following optimization problem and this is what I have done so far:

Cuppa Coffee Company mixes specialty coffee blends to sell to SmartBux, a small
chain of coffee shops. The ingredients for their specialty coffee are the following beans:

$$ \begin{array}{ l c r }
  BeanType & CostperPound & Available Amt \\
  Columbian & $1.00 & 550 \\
  Brazilian & $0.85 & 450 \\
  Sumatran & $1.55 & 650 \\
\end{array} $$

Cuppa’s products are:
- Robust Joe must consist of 60%–75% Sumatran beans and at least 10% Columbian beans. Each pound of Robust Joe can be sold to SmartBux for $4.25.

- Light Joe must consist of 50%–60% Brazilian beans and no more than 20% Sumatran beans. Each pound of Light Joe can be sold to SmartBux for $3.95.

Formulate an LP to maximize total profit. The answer to this should be $4902.50.

I have the following set up:

First of all, I tried to calculate the profit from making the coffee roasts as:

- Robust Joe: $.60(1.55) + .10(1.00)=   1.03$ (cost to make one pound), and subtracted it from the selling price: $4.25 - 1.03 = $3.22$.
- Light Joe: $.50(0.85) + .20(1.55) = 0.74$ (rounded up, cost to make one pound), and subtracted it from the selling price: $3.95 - 0.74 = 3.21$.

I used these numbers in my objective function below.

$x_1$ = pounds of Robust Joe produced.

$x_2$ = pounds of Light Joe produced.

Objective Function: profit = $3.22x_1 + 3.21x_2$

For my constraints, I tried to use the amounts of bean available, as:

$.10x_1 \leq 550$

$.50x_2 \leq 450$

$.60x_1 + .20x_2 \leq 650$

$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$

Is this set up correct? Does it take into account all the parameters that are needed to solve this problem?

Comment: This looks all wrong, you need the variables to represent ? Proportion of each bean in mix

Comment: How would I do this? The only way I can think of currently is to use two separate inequalities for variation in bean proportion.